How to serialize a Dart:ui Path?
I am displaying pathes using CustomPainter that come from converted SVGs (and later from user paint)
Because these pathes are to be editable by the users, CustomPainter seems like a good candidate.
However, I'm struggling with the recording of the Path in the database.
It appears that there is no simple serialization...
An option would be to "record" the commands of the path when it is initially created, and to store this list of records instead of the actual path. However, it would require some significant work to implement this within the svg parser.
Would you have any options to suggest to serialize or deserialize a Path in order to save it in a database? Or another approach that would answer to that use case?
Thank you so much for your suggestions!

there is no way to get the Path segments, what you could save is d attribute

That could potentially work from SVG soirces. But once the pathes are edited by the user, or even drawn from scratch, the svg source is either obsolete,  or doesn't exist at all...

yes, in such case create your own, custom Path class and make some method that returns such encoded String
